# how to fix "[options] target value 7 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release" in android studio"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to write plain old java code in android studio, just a `System.out.println()`. Can someone explain me step by step how to change the version or whatever I need to do in order to stop getting the error? (sorry if my question sounds dumb but I've been trying to figure this out in the last 90 minutes)
My screen, if it helps

[image: screen]

I made a new module for java, but I keep getting this error even tough it prints the message

Comment: In your build.gradle file s an entry that defines source and target Java version as Java 7. Change it to 8.